# Helptext with Fieldset in VF page

Tags: fieldsets, helptext

How to show Helptext for a field when a VF page is formed dynamically using Fieldset? I have created the VF page. I have put a helptext in field level, but it is not coming automatically. My code snippet:

```
<table> 
  <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="f"> 
    <tr> 
      <td>
        <span>{!f.label}</span>
      </td> 
      <td> 
        <apex:inputField value="{!vxSupp[f.fieldPath]}" required=" 
                         {!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}" /> 
      </td> 
    </tr> 
   </apex:repeat> 
</table>
```

Comment: I would assume that the help defined on each field is automatically presented. Is that a wrong assumption?

Comment: Have you created this Visualforce page yet? If so, it would help if you shared it with us. I'd imagine that using something other than `<apex:inputField>` would make things more bothersome.

Comment: I have created the VF page. I have put a helptext in field level, but it is not coming automatically. My code snippet:

<table>
  <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="f">
    <tr>
      <td><span>{!f.label}</span></td>
      <td>
        <apex:inputField value="{!vxSupp[f.fieldPath]}" required="{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}" />
          </td>
         </tr>
       </apex:repeat>
     </table>

Comment: you should [edit] your question to include that.